# time_zone issue in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_schedule_up" {  
 scheduled_action_name                  = "up"
  max_size                              = var.max_size
  min_size                              = var.min_size
  desired_capacity                      = var.desired_capacity
  recurrence                            = var.asg_cron
  time_zone                             = "Europe/London"
  autoscaling_group_name                = aws_autoscaling_group.asg_up.name
}
```

Error:
in resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_schedule_up":
231:   time_zone                             = var.asg_time_zone

An argument named "time_zone" is not expected here.

Can someone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: your code is named `asg_schedule_up` but your error is for `asg_schedule_down`.

Comment: What version of the AWS Terraform provider are you using? I don't think Amazon always let you specify the time zone, so you may need a newer version of the Terraform provider to use that feature. If you see something in the documentation that is "unavailable" to you locally, that is always an indication that you need to upgrade the provider version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have aws provider version <= 3.52.0

"time_zone" attribute got introduced from 3.53.0

Reference: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md